# initializing systemctl status mariadb.service

Tags: linux, mariadb

I'm trying to initialize the mysql service, with camando systemctl mariadb.service status, but the below error occurs, already uninstalled and installed twice, but the error persists.

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.0 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Seg 2016-03-14 17:51:49 BRT; 15s ago
  Process: 6303 ExecStopPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-wait-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6074 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


  Process: 6073 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6020 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5987 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6073 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 14 17:51:45 siad01-pc systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.0 database server...
Mar 14 17:51:46 siad01-pc mysqld_safe[6073]: 160314 17:51:46 mysqld_safe Log....
Mar 14 17:51:47 siad01-pc mysqld_safe[6073]: 160314 17:51:47 mysqld_safe Sta...l
Mar 14 17:51:48 siad01-pc mysqld_safe[6073]: 160314 17:51:48 mysqld_safe mys...d
Mar 14 17:51:48 siad01-pc systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exit...=1
Mar 14 17:51:49 siad01-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.0 database...r.
Mar 14 17:51:49 siad01-pc systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Mar 14 17:51:49 siad01-pc systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@siad01-pc ~]#
```

Comment: `Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.` Can you please provide the full log?

Comment: In other words show the output of `systemctl --no-pager -l status mariadb.service`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem.
I had to remove mysql, mariadb

## yum remove mysql

Then I removed /var/lib/mysql and then reinstalled mariadb, mariadb-server, mysql and mysql-server.

then i reinstalled mariadb

Its that simple